# ASP.NET MVC list sort methods not applicable

Tags: c#, list, sorting, model-view-controller

I have a list of objects. I wanted to sort it by its value. But sorting functions show errors and can not apply in Visual Studio. I use an ASP.NET MVC 5 controller to develop this code.

```
class keyValues
{
    string key;
    int value;

    public keyValues(string k, int v)
    {
        this.key   = k;
        this.value = v;
    }
}
```

In my controller

```
List<keyValues> generatedNumberList = new List<keyValues>();

generatedNumberList.Add(new keyValues("num1", 50));
generatedNumberList.Add(new keyValues("num2", 25));
generatedNumberList.Add(new keyValues("num3", 32));
generatedNumberList.Add(new keyValues("num4", 64));
generatedNumberList.Add(new keyValues("num5", 46));

var orderByValue = generatedNumberList.OrderBy(x=>x.value);
var sortByValue = generatedNumberList.Sort();
```

[image]

Comment: 1) `x.value` error because `value` is private. 2) `Sort` returns `void` hence the compilation error. 3) seems like you're coming from Java given the namings in your code, in C# you should favor PascalCasing

Comment: no it returns string, created using sorted array

Comment: Ok... show the definition of the `Sort` method.

Comment: yes, when make it "public int value;" it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `x.value` yields an error because `value` is private.
2. `Sort` returns `void` hence the compilation error.
3. seems like you're coming from Java given the namings in your code,
   in C# you should favor PascalCase instead of camelCase
4. I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel by creating a KeyValue class instead look into `KeyValuePair`, `Tuple`, `ValueTuple`.
5. Look into [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) in C#.